# Click event not working in bootgrid formatters

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-bootgrid

In JQuery-bootgrid formatters I am not able to call the click method.
If you have any idea what could be wrong please post here.

How to use the click event in KO using bootgrid?

This is my code:

```
function VM() { 
  var self = this; 
  self.GetDetails = function(_e,actionType) { 
    alert("Hi"); 
  } 
} 
var s = $("#UserList").bootgrid(
  { caseSensitive: false, 
    formatters: { 
      "Actions": function (column, curr) { 
         return "<a href='#' data-bind='click:GetDetails' class='on-default edit-row'>Hello</a>"; 
      } 
    } 
  }
).bootgrid("append", data); 
vm = new VM(); 
ko.applyBindings(vm,document.getElementById("MyDiv")[0]); 
})
```

Comment: Please provide some of your code that you've already tried so people could either correct it or at least get a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: add the JS and html code to the original answer, not as a comment.

Comment: I added your code from the comment to your question.